# Autosuggest modificar CSS para enviarlo como parte del formulario

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy realizando un proyecto con react y laravel y he usado un autosuggest para un campo de mi formulario que necesita funcionar con autocomplete.
Mi pregunta es como trabajo el css del componente dando el mismo estilo de los otros botones.

```html
<Autosuggest
                 onSuggestionsFetchRequested={onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
                  onSuggestionsClearRequested={onSuggestionsClearRequested}
                  onSuggestionSelected={onSuggestionSelected}
                  getSuggestionValue={suggestion => suggestion.label}
                  renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
                  inputProps={inputProps}
                />
```